# Syntax analysis for a complicated sentence

Tags: sentence-structure

I just received an email with this sentence, and while I think I understand what it is trying to say, I have difficulties trying to discover what case applies in which part, and generally in breaking it down in smaller pieces.

> Die Angabe aller Geschäftsführer einer GmbH mit Namen in der eMail-Signatur zählt zu den gesetzlichen Pflichtangaben für eMail-Signaturen.

Can someone explain me what the syntax analysis for this sentences is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is known as *Nominalstil*. The noun phrase* in front of the verb *zählt* can be compared to a sentence like the following, where 1 is an object (*wen*?), 2 is an adverbial of manner (*wie?*) and 3 is an adverbial of place (*wo*?).

> Man muß [alle Geschäftsführer einer GmbH]<sub>1</sub> [mit Namen]<sub>2</sub> [in der eMail-Signatur]<sub>3</sub> angeben.

Assuming by *cases* you meant *noun cases*: *einer GmbH* is genitive (because it is an attribute of a noun), *Namen* is dative (because of *mit*), *der eMail-Signatur* is dative (because the preposition is *in* and the question is *where?*).

<sup>*</sup> Wikipedia has an article on [noun phrases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_phrase). The idea is that nouns can be expanded:

> Untersuchung
>   die Untersuchung
>   die geforderte Untersuchung
>   die geforderte Untersuchung des Betriebs
>   die geforderte Untersuchung des Betriebs auf Salmonellen

In your example, the noun phrases in front of the verb is

> die Angabe aller Geschäftsführer einer GmbH mit Namen in der eMail-Signatur

Comment: Well, I do not know what a "noun phrase" is, but I guess that would need its own question page. Thanks!

Comment: @EnriqueMorenoTent A *noun phrase* is a phrase that functions grammatically as a noun. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_phrase

Comment: But doesn't a phrase need to have a verb? I see no verb inside that "noun phrase"

Comment: Are you perhaps mixing up clauses and phrases? Anyhow, it is useful to have a term like *phrase* to express the fact that most parts of speech can occur as parts of larger units: *happy* in *happy about the result*, *recklessly* in *quite recklessly*, *difficulties* in *difficulties with math*, etc.

Comment: I did not know the difference between clauses and phrases! That is very interesting and useful info. Thank you!